# when does insert define to jsonb if there are string values with \u0000 and how to use triggers to replace string segment with 'null' or empty

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger, jsonb

At what point is json/jsonb type defined?  Im trying to to define jsonb but plan to insert where there can be invalid input.  I am trying to account for it on an above business layer, but i think the db should handle this lifting with triggers and procedures.

The rules for jsonb is that strings in the json cant contain `\u0000` and I said to myself, well maybe there is a trigger i can use before insert, to do a string replace on all of those, but i wasnt sure how psql works with regards to this.  Since the table column is jsonb, would it error before the trigger occurs, or can this intercept be used to properly sanitize all string values.

While I was going to sanitize this on a business layer above, I was thinking that maybe the DB should be able to handle this kind of issue instead of erroring, it should be able to handle based on my use case.

For the example below I have a table called:

```
CREATE TABLE DEVICE (
  device_data jsonb not null
)
```

Here is the starting thought I was working with.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_update_strings()
RETURN TRIGGER as $$
BEGIN
  -- do string sanitization here for all STRINGS in object. Recursively (to account for arrays and sub-objects)
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sanitize_jsonb_object
BEFORE INSERT on public.device
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.jsonb_update_strings()
-- Execute other procedures with regard to other types tbd.
```

I am trying to account for the use cases in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html which I replace the strings accordingly.

Im certain this has been done, but im not sure how.

*Edit 1*  I was looking at the REPLACE function, which follows this flow: `REPLACE ('ABC AA', 'A', 'Z');` and would return `ZBC ZZ` so i was thinking to apply it above in the procedure.

```
BEGIN
   NEW.device_data = REPLACE(NEW.device_data, "\u0000", "null")
END;
```

Comment: Hi Fallenreaper. You're right jsonb will error, Json won't. Should the database deal with this? Your app sounds the ideal place to do this type of work and then present to the database. What do you think?

Comment: RFC 7159 permits JSON strings to contain Unicode escape sequences denoted by \uXXXX. In the input function for the json type, Unicode escapes are allowed regardless of the database encoding, and are checked only for syntactic correctness (that is, that four hex digits follow \u). However, the input function for jsonb is stricter: it disallows Unicode escapes for non-ASCII characters (those above U+007F) unless the database encoding is UTF8. The jsonb type also rejects \u0000 (because that cannot be represented in PostgreSQL's text type)

Comment: Ref https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Comment: Ah, ok.  Yeah, i wanted to use JSONB as it is preferential for the operations I am doing.  That being said, I was hoping that doing a sanitize via Trigger would be cool, but i didnt know if before injection into the DB if it is still a jsonb object.  If it was character or json, it wouldnt error, then i could sanitize in the before trigger (through a procedure), but i wasnt sure how types worked... If it was a JSONB before insert or if there was an intermediary type.  It seemed that with my initial tests the before insert on, would have it as a jsonb, so it would fail before sanitization.